# How to improve performance when displaying many views on a screen?

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm relatively a beginner at android. What I want to achieve is having many (up to 100) views on a screen and then animate it without it lagging. From what I've tried so far, having a lot of imageviews on one screen causes the stuttering and not the animation. I'm generating the imageviews dynamically and setting it to a drawable image then adding it to the layout which I'm guessing is related to the problem.

Are there more efficient ways of holding a lot of views in one layout without causing the stuttering? Thanks.

Edit: Thought I'll add a screenshot to make it easier to see what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F98PG.jpg

Comment: Consider just drawing all the bitmaps/images to a single view on your own and avoid the overhead of lots of views.  Be careful to only draw the parts of the bitmaps that are going to be visible at any moment.  Consider buffering the results of your draws so that the next request to onDraw doesn't have to internally re-draw everything to the Canvas again.

Comment: I've added a picture to show you what I meant. I could make it in one view but I don't think I can animate each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code so you use less Views .. so some code needs to be in your custom onDraw and some you can leave in hierarchy to make your life easier.

I similarly had issue with performance when zooming in out bunch of views and I changed my design so I basically convert some of the view types to custom drawing code.  I had rows and keys in rows and some other views inside of keys, Now I have just rows and those user clickable views inside rows rest is drawn...  And sure I have to position and partially also size them now manually in rows and update them too when zoom changes instead of using view layout hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

The [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) is absolutely solves your problem. There are many How To's, for example you can start with this:

http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/

Comment: I know how to use a recyclerview but I'm not sure how this would help because each view has to be present on the screen at the same time and animate individually from the rest.